# JBPM RuntimeManager is null for Old Task after Tomcat Restart or Application Redployed

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jbpm

After successful setup of JBPM Spring Rest Application, I successfully deployed it on Tomcat 8, deployed and started a process, complete one task, then redeployed the application without any modification (clean redeployed) , I can see the old task but when I try to complete the task, apparently it does not give any error but process remain on the same stage, while debugging I noticed that runtime manager is null i.e. getRuntimeManager(UserTaskInstanceDesc task) method from taskService return Null, what could be the possible reason?

Other Information

- JBPM 6.2
- application is using mysql database
- Deployed on Tomcat Server 8

Please note that I deployed and started the same process again,everything work fine for new process, I been able to complete the task, but still not been able to complete the old task.

any idea?

Comment: Can you specify which version of JBPM you are using?